# Prove $X_t =$ $\sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty \psi_j * Y_{t-j} = \psi (B) * Y_t$ is stationary?

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, covariance, trend, moving-average

I was going through my time series text and I found a curious identity that the book just says is true without actually going in depth to prove it. I am unable to figure out how this works, so I would appreciate pointers.

The theorem states:

"Let {$Y_t$} be a stationary process w/ mean 0 and a covariance function $\gamma_Y$. If $\sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty |\psi_Y| < \infty$, then the process

$X_t =$ $\sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty \psi_j * Y_{t-j} = \psi (B) * Y_t$

is stationary with mean 0 and autocovariance

$\gamma_X (h)$ = $\sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty \psi_j*\psi_k*\gamma_y (h+k-j)$"

I presume $B$ is the backshift operator.

I'm having trouble mentally parsing what  $X_t$ even means; specifically the meaning of  $\sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty |\psi_Y| < \infty$ and what role it even plays. Is it a moving average filter? If so, why would we combine that with the backshift?

Comment: Since $X_t$ has a definition that does not refer to the backshift operator, why not just ignore everything that refers to $B$?  You won't lose a thing.

Comment: Even after fixing various typos, (e.g. what is $Y$ in $\sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty |\psi_Y| < \infty$ and why is there no $j$ in the summand?), I don't think the result is correct unless in the time-series literature "stationary" always means what would ordinarily be called weakly stationary or wide-sense-stationary, or time-series are always normal processes (Gaussian processes) unless explicitly stated to be otherwise.  The condition $\sum_{j=-\infty}^\infty |\psi_j| < \infty$ is needed to ensure that $X_t$  is the limit of a convergent sequence of random variables.